# Customizing CheckBoxPreference via android:widgetLayout

Tags: android, preference

I have a `Preference` that enables a sync adapter, and takes a while to actually do its work when toggled.  Consequently, when the user clicks the `Preference`, I spin off an AsyncTask to do the work. In the meantime, I disable the `Preference` and replace the check box with an indeterminate `ProgressBar`.  I have all of this working via a hack involving a subclass of `CheckBoxPreference` that overlays the `ProgressBar` on top of the `CheckBox`.  Yuck.

The `android:widgetLayout` attribute seems like it's designed exactly for this.  I should be able to use `android:widgetLayout` to specify a replacement for the default `CheckBox`.  Said replacement would implement `Checkable` and use a `ViewSwitcher` to switch appropriately between a `CheckBox` and a `ProgressBar`.

The only problem is that `CheckBoxPreference`, in its `onBindView()` method, seems to ignore the possibility that `android:widgetLayout` may be used.  It explicitly does this:

```
View checkboxView = view.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.checkbox);
```

This effectively makes it impossible to swap in a custom `Checkable` via `android:widgetLayout` and have it actually work.

Is this an oversight/bug in `CheckBoxPreference`, or have I misunderstood `android:widgetLayout`?  Is there a cleaner intended way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've just hit it too.

Comment: Not really.  I stuck with [my subclass](https://github.com/loganj/foursquared/blob/master/main/src/com/joelapenna/foursquared/preferences/ProgressCheckBoxPreference.java) of `CheckBoxPreference`.

Answer (score 12):

1. First, I agree with you that Android should refactor the piece of code `view.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.checkbox);` to "calling a protected method" which can be overrided by subclass.
2. Luckily, we are still able to override work around as follows:
   The idea is simple: declare a checkbox which has id is android default id `@android:id/checkbox`

> `<CheckBoxPreference
>
>       android:key="autostart"
>
>       android:widgetLayout="@layout/customlayout" />`

and in customlayout.xml:

> `<SwitchView>
>
>   ...
>
>   <CheckBox>`
>          android:id="**@android:id/checkbox**"
>          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>          android:text="mycheck"
>          android:clickable="false"
>          **android:focusable="false"**
>          **android:focusableInTouchMode="false"**
>   `</CheckBox>`

It's really important to note that **focusable attributes of checkbox must be set to false** (I guess the default layout of CheckBoxPreference does the same thing) so that list apdater receives event rather than the checkbox itself. 
I guess you didn't success in your try just because you didn't set the focusable state.

greensuisse
(https://sites.google.com/site/greensuisse/)

Comment: Awesome! It works. Thanks for mentioning to put them to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

android:widgetLayout is the right part of the preference. In the CheckBoxPreference, the widgetLayout is the checkbox.
If you take a base Preference and put a ViewSwitcher in the widgetLayout, it should work

Comment: Sure, but then I miss out on the stuff CheckBoxPreference does, like summaries and accessibility.